# Loop following webbrowser document complete

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VBA, how to wait for Webbrowser to completely load before moving to next row and executing Call, please see code below, any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Have tried using Worksheet_SelectionChange with no success, as the script executes ActiveCell.Row select without stopping.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheet1.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    Sheet1.Cells.Borders.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    Sheet1.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    Sheet1.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Borders.Color = vbRed
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 3).Borders.Color = vbRed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select
'HOW TO LOOP Call AutoDomain with using Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select?
'while waiting for webbrowser to completely load before moving to next row and executing Call AutoDomain
'Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
'AutoDomain
    End
End Sub
Sub AutoDomain()
    Dim xURL As String
    Application.Speech.Speak "Starting Look Up", Speakasync:=True, Purge:=True
    xURL = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)
    Cells(1, 3).Value = ""
    Cells(1, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Cells(1, 3).Borders.Color = xlNone
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value = ""
    WebBrowser1.Silent = True
    WebBrowser1.Navigate (xURL)
    Sheets(1).Calculate
    End
End Sub
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
    WebBrowser1.Stop
    URL = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)
    Cells(1, 3).Value = WebBrowser1.LocationURL
    Cells(1, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
    Cells(1, 3).Borders.Color = vbRed
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value = "DOMAIN : " & WebBrowser1.LocationURL & vbCrLf & "TITLE  : " & WebBrowser1.LocationName
    Do Until Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value <> ""
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.Speech.Speak " Look Up Completed ", Speakasync:=True, Purge:=True
    'SPEECH IS CONTINUING EXTRA TIMES WITHOUT STOPPING SOMETIME, used END to attempt to force speech to stop
    End
End Sub
```

Comment: Calling `Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select` inside `Worksheet_SelectionChange` can cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this custom sub which works in about 90% of my cases where I need to wait for the page to load:

```
Sub Wait()

While (IE.Busy Or IE.READYSTATE <> 4): DoEvents: Wend
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

End Sub
```

You would need to replace `IE` with `WebBrowser1`.

So you could put that at the bottom of your module, then change your line to:

`WebBrowser1.Navigate (xURL): Wait`

Comment: Thank you, using Application.Wait on DocumentComplete.